# Unable to enable Startup Sound in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in Startup Application via the command that was used in 21.10 to enable startup sound

Tags: sound, startup, startup-applications

[image: Startup Application Status]
Please help me find out a way to enable startup sound as I'm highly used to it being a Windows user for a long time, where you just had to click a checkbox to enable startup sound...

Comment: Did you add `canberra-gtk-play --id="system-ready"` to the command box?

Comment: What is that? Is it just to be added to the command I had already entered or only the command specified is supposed to be there in the command box? @INTINV

Comment: Or simply, can you post a full answer stating each step to be taken to enable startup sound? @INTINV

Comment: @INTINV It's been a long time since I waited for your reply! Thereby I'm pinging you again to draw your attention to this issue I'm facing - please post a full answer regarding the steps required to be taken in order to enable Startup Sound in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Follow the steps below as directed:**

1. *Open* **Startup Application**.
2. *Click* **Add**.
3. Add any ***suitable name*** to this **program** so that it can be ***easily identified***.
4. *Copy* the following **code** and ***paste*** it in the **Command box**: `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`
5. *Add* any ***suitable comment*** to *describe* the **program**.
   *At last*, click *Add* to **initialize the program at the next Startup**.

[This is how it must look before saving the program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdGQy.png)

*In the end*, *click* **Save** and then *click* **Close**. With the next **reboot**, you'll be able to ***hear*** the **startup sound**.